# Windows 7 & Git Bash: Doesn't Recognize pear/phpunit

Tags: windows-7, shell, git, git-bash

I can run pear/phpunit from "cmd" just fine. I checked %PATH% and everything that is there is also in $PATH.

To be clear, this is not msysgit -- It is this:
http://git-scm.com/downloads

Anyone know how I can make it get recognized?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you invoking it and what is the actual error message you're receiving?

Comment: typing in "pear" and "phpunit" from Git Bash -- like I do in "cmd". It was working on a Windows XP computer (which I don't have access to at the moment). Error: sh.exe": pear: command not found

Comment: @Kerry, just to clarify, the versions of git found here http://git-scm.com/ and here http://msysgit.github.io/ are the same build. There's no difference. What you linked is the same as Msysgit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was not in fact with the PATH (which was matching my Windows path perfectly). The problem is that Git Bash does not run ".bat" files:
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=426

To run a batch file you have to do a work around:

```
cmd "/c /path/to/batch.bat"
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865085/out-of-a-git-console-how-do-i-execute-a-batch-file-and-then-return-to-git-conso

The solution in my case was to make an alias for phpunit in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
alias phpunit='cmd "/c phpunit.bat"'
```

Hope that helps anyone else with the same problem.

---

**UPDATE**

I discovered that if you want to use arguments (such as specific a specific file to test) you will need to change what you put in your `.bash_profile` to the following:

```
function __phpunit {                                                                
    cmd "/c phpunit.bat $@"  
} 

alias phpunit=__phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .phar extension and disregard making the bat file if you're using an editor that isn't command prompt.

In the last line on the Windows installation documentation for phpunit it reads:

> For Cygwin and/or MingW32 (e.g., TortoiseGit) shell environments, you may skip step 5. above, simply save the file as phpunit (without .phar extension), and make it executable via chmod 775 phpunit.

source: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

The Git Bash install that you linked is using MINGW32. That is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use alias native will be much better.
edit ~/.bashrc, add these in it:

```
alias phpunit="php /C/Tools/php/phpunit.phar" // phpunit.phar in C:\Tools\php\phpunit.phar
```